# JavaScript: How to use asynchronous methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I want to get the result:

```
1
2
3
```

How to do it?

I've tried several implementation options, but they all do not produce the same result that I want.

if use:

```
var aaa = {
    line: function () {
        console.log(1)
        aaa.RF();
        console.log(3)
    },
    RF: async function () {
        await jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
            console.log(2)
        })
    }
}
aaa.line()
```

result:

```
1
3
2
```

if

```
console.log(4)
async jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
    await console.log(5)
})
console.log(6)
```

result err

if

```
console.log(1)
async function a() {
    await jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
         console.log(2)
    })
}
a()
console.log(3)
```

result:

```
1
3
2
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to `await aaa.RF()`. Without adding that `await`, it still treats the `async` function as async and just continues along.

```
var aaa = {
    line: async function () {
        console.log(1)
        await aaa.RF();
        console.log(3)
    },
    RF: async function () {
        await jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
            console.log(2)
        })
    }
}
aaa.line()
```

Comment: No, result 1,3,2

Comment: Try `console.log(await new Promise(r => jsonfile.readFile(file, () => r(2))))`.

Comment: @VINET Can you update your question with the latest code?

Comment: @samanime, Please show me how to accomplish this with the object and I will update the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... I gave you the exact code to fix your first example.